# What will be the simplest circuit that outputs 1 when it receives a predefined WiFi packet?

Tags: wifi

What will be the simplest circuit that outputs 1 when it receives a predefined or pre-programmed WiFi packet? Lets suppose that I connect this circuit to an appropriate antenna then I want that my circuit lights a LED when it receives a specific WiFi packet. I don't want to use a WiFi radio or a micro controller, just discrete components. Is this possible?

Comment: Nope.  You'll need a processor of some kind.

Comment: The simplest circuit will be much more complex than a WiFi radio (eg. NodeMCU, ATWINC, ATWILC etc.).

Comment: While this isn't going to work for wifi, what *may* solve your problem is using OOK in the 433mhz band, which can have really simple receivers.

Comment: @pcj50 has a point. Maybe ask a new question that explains what you want to solve, and asks for advice how to solve the actual problem. Your "I want to detect a specific WiFi packet" sounds **very** much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What will be the simplest circuit that outputs 1 when it receives a predefined or pre-programmed WiFi packet?

Something that "speaks" Wifi enough to detect packets on the air, synchronize to them, extract the bits from them, apply forward error correction (the likelihood of you ever receiving a full WiFi data frame without a single bit error goes strongly towards 0), and then does a comparison.

In other words,

> I don't want to use a WiFi radio or a micro controller, just discrete components. Is this possible?

No. Not at all.